# Problema AndroidStudio não funciona no AVD

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, debug

Boa Noite estou com um problema, não faço ideia do que possa ser preciso muito da ajuda de vocês! estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo Android em Android studio no código está tudo correto compila legal não possui erro de sintaxe , mas no momento de emular isso apresenta o seguinte erro.

***Obs.: Esse erro ocorre em todas as emulações não só no GenyMotion , Mas na propria AVD do android studio também no galaxy etc...***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**LOG DE ERRO GERADO :**

```
07-30 21:15:17.200 402-402/? E/vinput: Vinput is not configured. The command mouse_press is ignored
07-30 21:15:17.203 352-552/system_process E/EventHub: could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
07-30 21:15:17.415 391-391/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 164 ms
07-30 21:15:17.415 391-391/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 164 ms
07-30 21:15:17.479 401-401/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 401: eglCreateSyncKHR(1881): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
07-30 21:15:17.479 401-401/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 401: eglCreateSyncKHR(1881): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
07-30 21:15:18.116 1124-1237/com.android.launcher3 E/EGL_emulation: tid 1237: eglSurfaceAttrib(1210): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
07-30 21:15:18.138 416-416/? E/OMXNodeInstance: setConfig(0xf3ea10e0:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigPriority(0x6f800002)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
07-30 21:15:18.140 416-801/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf3ea10e0:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
07-30 21:15:18.463 352-366/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

**Minha activity_main.xml está da seguinte forma :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/my_bg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
            app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="5dp"
            app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        />

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignActive"
            app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="5dp"
            app:cornerRadius="4dp"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="307dp"
        android:layout_height="299dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="47dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="117dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_eat_it" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Minha MainActivity.java esta da seguinte forma:**

```
package com.example.user.androidbillfood;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnSignIn,btnSignUp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
        btnSignUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

            }
        });


        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Você já tentou criar um projeto do zero, vazio e mandou emular no AVD do Android studio? Se sim, roda normal?

Comment: Ainda não fiz dessa forma vou fazer o teste ! E mando o resultado. Não descarto a hipótese de que possa ser problema no Gradle também! Mas vou fazer o teste.